# Jenkins Job Error: "Operation not permitted" on macOS Agent

Tags: macos, jenkins

I set up an macOS jenkins agent and tried to ran jenkins job on it, job failed with "Operation not permitted":
[image]

Remark: macOS agent is launched via ssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by secure setting on macOS agent, enable sshd-keygen-wrapper `Full Disk Access` fixed this issue:

[image]